# How do I test binary floating point math functions

Tags: testing, math, floating-point, pow

I implemented the `powf(float x, float y)` math function. This function is a binary floating point operation. I need to test it for correctness，but the test can't iterate over all floating point. what should I do.

Comment: You can do randomized testing maybe with exhaustive testing of some border cases. Or you can try to formally proof the correctness of your implementation. Some helper functions can perhaps be tested exhaustively.

Comment: Have a look at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40541/what-are-some-good-strategies-to-test-a-floating-point-arithmetic-implementation

Comment: why you can not iterate through all floats? its just `(2^32)^2` options ...

Comment: think I'd embed a few unit tests for a quick "sanity" check of the results and have some machine do longer term randomised/fuzz tests as well.  there are "[coverage based](https://llvm.org/docs/LibFuzzer.html)" systems that can help you explore the space more efficiently than just sampling uniformly

Comment: @Spektre (2^64) is a huge number. You can use youself computer to iterate (2^32),then estimate the time.

Comment: @xiaohuihui 2^64 is still manageable number of tests on current computers (unless your code runs on some silly slow stuff like python or is not efficiently written)... I am doing this time to time and I have ~12+ years old PC... You can start with quick test covering some ranges (or "random" values) and once passed (after tweaking code) do a full test. Does not matter if it will take 5 min its important to be sure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider 2 questions:

> How do I test binary floating point math functions?

Break FP values into groups:

- Largest set: Normal values including +/- values near 1.0 and near the extremes as well as randomly selected ones.
- Subnormals
- Zeros: +0.0, -0.0
- NANs

Use *at least* combinations of 100,000s+ sample values from the first set (including +/-min, +/-1.0, +/-max), 1,000s from the second set (including +/-min, +/-max) and -0.0, +0.0, -NAN, +NAN.

Additional tests for the function's edge cases.

---

> How do I test `powf()`?

How: Test `powf()` against `pow()` for result correctness.

Values to test against: `powf()` has many concerns.

`*pow(x,y)` functions are notoriously difficult to code well.  The error in little sub-calculations errors propagate to large final errors.

`*pow()` includes expected *integral* results with *integral* value arguments.  E.g. `pow(2, y)` is expected to be exact for all in range results.  `pow(10, y)` is expected to be within 0.5 unit in the last place for all `y` in range.

`*pow()` includes expected *integer* results with negative `x`.

There is little need to test every `x`, `y` combination.  Consider every `x < 0`, `y non-whole number value` leads to a NAN.

`z = powf(x,y)` readily underflows to 0.0. Testing of `x, y`, values near a result of `z == 0` needs some attention.

`z = powf(x,y)` readily overflows to ∞. Testing of `x, y`, values near a result of `z == FMT_MAX` needs more attention as a slight error result in `FLT_MAX` vs. `INF`.   Since overflow is so rampant with `powf(x,y)`, this reduces the numbers of combinations needed as it is the edge that is important and larger values need light testing.

Comment: thank your answer. I spent a lot of time testing this function.